# logged in on X without environment

Tags: x11, autologin, getty

I have an rpi2. I want the same Black Screen that you get after Arch installation (without graphical environment), the only difference is that it automatically logs in with your user account.
I installed Arch/LXQT/sddm and tigervnc on my rpi2.

I can run `ssh user@ip-address` from my laptop and log into my rpi2 and then when I start `tigervnc` it works like a charm, but I want, if possible, to automate the login from rpi2 and only fire up `tigervnc` from my laptop

1. I tried this:

   in `/etc/sddm.conf`:

   ```
   #Session=lxqt.desktop
   #RememberLastSession=false
   User=username
   ```
2. I also created a shortcut in the directory 
   `/usr/share/xsessions/X.desktop` which contains:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec="sudo agetty ttyX -a username"
   Name=X
   Comment=X
   ```

   and changed `/etc/sddm.conf` to:

   ```
   Session=X.desktop
   #RememberLastSession=false
   User=username
   ```

   A. first of all without login in rpi the vnc server doesnt work as a user-service /home/user/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/vncserv‌​er@:1.service

   B. all i want is to open the vnc from my laptop and log into the LXQT, but on rpi side i want only TTY autologin. imagine how taxing is to run both LXQT desktops (rpi natively and on vnc) and both are loading from rpi.

Comment: so my bad English is the problem here... thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @ΗλιαςΤσορομωκος Χαίρετε! No, your English isn't a problem.

Comment: Ηλία, your English is fine. As a local mod (και ως συμπατριώτης), I would like to apologize for peterh's comment. He could have chosen to edit your post but instead chose to leave that snide comment. Sorry about that! This site is open to all, and while we do expect people to put some effort into their questions, as you clearly did, we do not require everyone to speak perfect English before posting here. Most people will just edit the post to correct any language issues.

Comment: Welcome συμπατριώτη. Don't be discouraged by the negative votes. Sometimes people prefer to reject things that they do not understand. And i have to admit that your question is "advanced level"....

Comment: It is unclear to me why you would say you want "(without graphical environment)" and then go on to install graphical environments (LXQT/sddm). Anyway, for TTY autologin, see if https://askubuntu.com/a/776197/158442 helps (I tested it on Arch, and it should work)

Comment: 1. first of all without login in rpi the vnc server doesnt work as a user-service /home/user/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/vncserver@:1.service 2. all i want is to open the vnc from my laptop and log into the LXQT, but on rpi side i want only TTY autologin. imagine how taxing is to run both LXQT desktops (rpi natively and on vnc) and both are loading from rpi.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was found at the post that muru suggested...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin/776197#776197

thanks a lot you guys!!
(i dont know how to add the user highlighted)